# Eclipse - manifest.mf plugin dependencies - different icons

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Greetings fellow Stackoverflownians,

I am developing an Eclipse RCP plugin, and have come across different icons in the Dependencies tab of the manifest file:

[image: icons 'n' stuff]

Anybody got a clue why the last one is different? My supposition is that it's coming from a different source, i.e. the Build Path, instead of the Target Platform.
It's a nebula for me, to be honest.

Any opinions and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be that icon on 'some.project.here' icon means the plugin is in your workspace, the other icon means the plugin comes from the target platform.

You can also get a small question mark overlayed on the image which means the plugin is optional. There is also a small arrow overlay which means the plugin dependency is marked as re-exported.

There is also an 01 overlay which I think means this a project imported using 'import plugins and fragments' with 'binary project' selected.

Comment: Thanks for this! What about when there is a 01 next to it?

Comment: Can you show a example with a "01"? I've never noticed this. But i guess it has something to do with "binary" packages without sources or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the plugin you are adding is in your package explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Yep you're right. The arrow means definitly that eclipse will resolve the dependency from the TargetPlatform. And the other one with the dot indicates, that it will resolve it from your local workspace.